# Convert Values with Timezone to timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to convert some values (in text format) to TIMESTAMP data type before loading to Oracle tables. The values are having Timezone info as in below samples:

**2018-05-28T14:32:53.5860707+08:00**

**2018-05-30T08:26:47.554801+08:00**

**2018-05-21T16:26:29.5443257+08:00**

Can you please help?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Do you like to convert the string into `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`? If you like to get `TIMESTAMP` - do you need any conversion, e.g. to local time or UTC?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to lose information by converting your data, which is timestamp with time zone, to simple timestamp. It should be timestamp with time zone; or, alternatively, timestamp with LOCAL time zone. Read the Oracle documentation about these data types if you are not familiar with them, then have a serious discussion with the **business users** who are the real owners of the data, to see what their needs are. WARNING: +08:00 may not be enough information, if daylight saving time is a consideration. +08:00 is an offset from UTC, which may be +09:00 in a time zone subject to DST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use to_timestamp_tz with format string 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FFTZH:TZM'. Put the "T" in quotes in the format string.

```
select 
   to_timestamp_tz('2018-05-28T14:32:53.5860707+08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FFTZH:TZM')
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

select 
   to_timestamp_tz('2018-05-28T14:32:53.5860707+08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FFTZH:TZM')
from dual